# Stored procedure, activerecord, and alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures, activerecord, powerbuilder

In a PowerBuilder-based project, there are overs three hundred stored procedures on a Microsoft SQL Server. It's a client-server application which relies a lot on PB's DataWindow.

Now, there is an feature request from the users which will most likely add several web-based screens to interface with the system.

We are evaluating Rails (for our team member experience) and CakePHP (for performance/deployment considerations).

We use a lot of ActiveRecord (on Rails, naturally) for other web-based projects. However, stored procedures and ActiveRecord do not play well with each other.

I'd like to hear your experience and suggestions on:

- how to minimize rewriting (duplicating) the stored proecedures in ActiveRecord
- besides what we are already looking at (Rails and CakePHP), what are the alternatives (say, DataWindow.NET?, LINQ?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Powerbuilder 11.5 Webform's datawindows work very nicely with stored procedures.  It works exactly the same as client-server Powerbuilder.  No rewrite at all.

Comment: I think they developing a new app rather than rewriting, but it's still a valid answer: PB Webforms if you've the in house talent, there is plenty of opportunity for code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer if you're only interested in SQL Server stored procedures is ASP.NET.  You could even consider IronRuby!